# Aggregating forecasts and their standard errors over time periods

Tags: forecasting, standard-error, aggregation

Good day all,

I have an ARIMA model which gives me a weekly forecast and standard error for each period.

If I were to aggregate the forecasts into monthly time-windows (for simplicity sake, let's assume that month = 4 weeks), how would I estimate the standard error for this new forecast?

My instinct would be to take the square root of the sum of squared standard errors for the 4 weekly periods but is that correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct because the forecast errors are correlated. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast-intervals-for-aggregates/

Comment: @RobHyndman Thank you, your website example makes perfect sense. I just need to find a way to replicate this in SQL now :) I suppose it's doable, something to chew on.